# Why await not waiting?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I was confronted with unexpected and strange behavior when working with async/await methods. Execution is breaking after calling await. There is no exceptions or async continue, just break and nothing. Here is code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MailChimpUser>> GetAllMembersAsync(string listName)
 {
  try
  {
   //Breaks here 
   var list = await GetListByName(listName);

   //Nevertheless, if extract method code
   //var lists = await _apiManager.Lists.GetAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
   //list = lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == name);
   //the execution will continueя

   var members = await _apiManager.Members.GetAllAsync(list.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

   var result = members.Select(m => new MailChimpUser()
   {
      ...
   } );
   //the same behavior here, after the return it does not return to the method that awaiting it.
   return result;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
   var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, new object[] { });
    throw ex;
  }   
 }

 private async Task<MailChimp.Net.Models.List> GetListByName(string name)
 {
    try
    {
        var lists = await _apiManager.Lists.GetAllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        var list = lists.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Name == name);

        if (list == null)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("MailChimp: List \"{0}\" not found", name));
        return list;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        logger.Error(ex, ex.Message, new object[] { });
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `throw ex;` should be `throw;`.

Comment: @UweKeim not if they explicitly wants to reset the stack trace

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "break"? I can't see where you call `GetAllMembersAsync`, only `GetAllAsync`.

Comment: Could you please better describe what happens with your application after reaching the marked point? Does it continue running or is it stuck? Is it a GUI application (WinForms, WPF)?

Comment: Did not helped.

Comment: Zdeněk Jelínek it realy strang but nothings happend. It  step to await  method and complitly nothings happend.

Comment: René Vogt the GetAllMembersAsync is the same strange behavior as GetListByName. It works if i extract metod code, but if i call GetListByName its step to it and do nothing

Comment: However, the application does not hang and continues to work

Comment: Please show how you call the methods. If you don't await those methods or try to access the `Result` of the returned `Task`s, you may miss an exceptions thrown by `GetListByName`.

Comment: var mailChimpMembers = await mailChimp.GetAllMembersAsync(listName);

Comment: The problem was in missing ConfigureAwait(false).  var mailChimpMembers = await mailChimp.GetAllMembersAsync(listName).ConfigureAwait(false);

Comment: We still can't see the whole callstack. But do read [Using ConfigureAwait(false) to avoid deadlocks is a dangerous practice](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Thanks Henk it is useful post

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I forgot  ConfigureAwait(false)

```
var list = await GetListByName(listName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```